# Issues refactoring GLES30 shader?

Tags: opengl-es, textures, glsl, shader, hlsl

I'm currently rewriting a shader written in GLES30 for the GLES20 shader language.

I've hit a snag where the shader I need to convert makes a call to the function `textureLod`, which samples the currently bound texture using a specific level-of-detail. This call is made within the fragment shader, [which can only be called within the vertex shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/reference_cards/OpenGL-ES-2_0-Reference-card.pdf) when using GLES20.

I'm wondering, if I replace this with a call with the function `texture2D`, will I be likely to compromise the function of the shader, or just reduce it's performance? All instances where the `textureLod` call is made within the original shader uses a level of detail of zero.

Comment: I've used this shadertoy and explicitly set the texture level-of-detail to 0.0, and it appears to sample the texture directly. Just wondering how this applies to a GL.GL_NEAREST mipmapping context.
https://www.shadertoy.com/view/4slGWn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you switch calls from `textureLod` to `texture2D`, you will lose control over which mip-level is being sampled.

If the texture being sampled only has a single mip-level, then the two calls are equivalent, regardless of the lod parameter passed to `textureLod`, because there is only one level that could be sampled.

If the original shader always samples the top mip level (=0), it is unlikely that the change could hurt performance, as sampling lower mip-levels would more likely give better texture cache performance. If possible, you could have your sampled texture only include a top level to guarantee equivalence (unless the mip levels are required somewhere else). If this isn't possible, then the execution will be different. If the sample is used for 'direct' texturing, it is likely that the results will be fairly similar, assuming a nicely generated mip-chain. If it is used for other purposes (eg. logic within the shader), then the divergence might be larger. It's difficult to predict without seeing the actual shader.

Also note that, if the texture sample is used within a loop or conditional, and has been ported to/from a DirectX HLSL shader at any point in its lifetime, the call to `textureLod` may be an artifact of HLSL not allowing gradient instructions within dynamic loops (of which the HLSL equivalent of `texture2D` is, but equivalent of `textureLod` is not). This is required in HLSL, even if the texture only has a single mip-level.